# Launchy vs Deskbar vs...?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, launchy

I know this is probably personal preference but I haven't tried out Launchy.  This is for Linux, specifically Ubuntu 9.04.

What do most people on here prefer, Launchy, deskbar, or another alternative?

---

**UPDATE - MY SOLUTION**

wow, just installed [Gnome-do](http://do.davebsd.com).  I'm using the docky theme, its MUCH more useful than deskbar and does exactly what deskbar does as well.  I've cleaned up my entire panel now, I only have one at the bottom so it looks kind of like windows, and I have the dock at the top with intellihide :-)

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I just noticed the intellihide yesterday... very nice feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[gnome-do](http://do.davebsd.com/) or [krunner](http://www.kde.org/announcements/4.0/desktop.php) which really is superior but I'm not currently using KDE.

GnomeDo also comes with the [Docky](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/index.php?title=Docky) interface which gives you a very cool dock.

So to sum up:

1. If using Gnome I use gnome-do
2. If using KDE I use krunner

Comment: I've tried them both, and gnome-do definitely trumps launchy in my opinion.

Comment: I've never used Launchy.

Comment: I've been using Deskbar and although I like it for its similarities to Spotlight (on Mac), its been crashing for me a lot.  It doesn't crash the system, but it exits with an error and needs to be reloaded to the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Kupfer and Wbar does better if you want something really lightweight but ubuntu is by far the worst distro to see a speed improvement, you should try ArchLinux by the Chakra live cd/dvd project and mod it to what you want ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be launchy, Here is an good [list](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/launchy/) . I prefer "[Everything](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/everything/)", but if you dont need to index your entire drive then stay with launchy.

Comment: Everything isn't really Linux :)